# how getting total count of notification watchface on Gear S

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-gear, watchface

I am trying to add a notifications feature to my watchface. I want to get total count of notifications on the Samsung Gear S and then when a specific areais clicked I would like to take the user to the "Notifications" app of the Samsung Gear.

Is this possible in javascript ? How ?

Thank you very much!